# parsing googledocs links into media iframe

Tags: php, html, iframe, google-docs

I'm trying to make googledocs links converted automatically into googledocs iframe on my forum,

something like this:

```
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Pj7M208A3qqTrcFGtQ295nGdewSj6YYa097fvvi7Ydo
```

will automatically changed to:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Pj7M208A3qqTrcFGtQ295nGdewSj6YYa097fvvi7Ydo/pub?embedded=true"></iframe>
```

so I write this code to my parser:

```
else if (preg_match('%docs.google.com%i', $url, $matches))
        return CreateGoogledocsEmbedCode($url);
```

and here is the key:

```
// Automatically parse googledocs links and generate the respective embed code
function CreateGoogledocsEmbedCode($url)
{
// Generate the embed code
$url = preg_replace('~(?:http|https|)(?::\/\/|)(?:docs.google.com(?:\/document\/d\S*[^\w\-\s]))(\d+)[a-z0-9;:@#?&%=+\/\$_.-]*~i', '<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/$1/edit" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>', $url);
return $url;
}
```

In my mind it will work properly, but actually it doesn't work. can anyone give me advice? here if you want to check the result [my media parser](http://www.suaraguru.com/viewtopic.php?id=28)
Thanks

Comment: what do these links look like before, and how do you want them to look after

Comment: Also not sure what this is for `(?:http|https|)` that ending `|` OR, that is.  Preg replace, you only need to capture what you are putting back into the url, and match what you are replacing, generally.  Most of that (?:) is irrelevent or better served this way `(?:http|https)?`

Comment: looks like you only are capturing this `(\d+)` id need a link to test it with though.  Couldn't you just do this part `(?:\/document\/d\S*[^\w\-\s])(\d+)` and use preg_match with the 4th parameter ( $matches ) to create the url.

Comment: Can you update the answer, with an example of a link before and after this operation runs, If you can do that I will give your regx for it a go.  Sorry I don't have time to try to guess what you need.  Pretend I have no idea what google docs are.  For intents and purposes we are just converting one piece of text to another.  In fact a few examples would be really useful.

Comment: I have update my question with the detail that you ask, please check on my question,

Comment: so.... the only thing different is this is on the end `/pub?embedded=true`, `https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Pj7M208A3qqTrcFGtQ295nGdewSj6YYa097fvvi7Ydo`, `https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Pj7M208A3qqTrcFGtQ295nGdewSj6YYa097fvvi7Ydo/pub?embedded=true` ? why dont you just append that then.  `$link.'/pub?embedded=true';`  if you need to match it in like a href attribute you can just do `/href=\"([^\"]+)\"/`

Comment: You can match the whole link like this. https://regex101.com/r/qI3hM0/2

Comment: how about the <iframe></iframe> tag?
I need it also to convert the link into iframe.

Comment: `<iframe src="'.$link.'"></iframe>`, I don't understand.  if you need a regx just replace `href` with `src`  such as `/src=\"([^\"]+)\"/`.  This is look for the word `[href]` an equal sign and a quote `="` then anything but a quote `[^\"]+` then a quote `"`

Comment: I'm sorry I'm confused, can you just give me the full code I have to write?

Comment: I have try this, but I dont know how to implement your advice and I got some error with it. So can you show me the full code that I have to write based on the code that I've made with implementation of your code?